Why can't I use AS when aliasing a subquery in Oracle SQL?
I was working on this Query and running into a 'command not properly ended' error.  I figured out it was due to how I was aliasing the subquery.
select ctable.code, company.founder, ctable.lman, ctable.sman, ctable.man, ctable.emp
from (select 
c.company_code as code, 
count(distinct l.lead_manager_code) as lman, 
count(distinct s.senior_manager_code) as sman,
count(distinct m.manager_code) as man,
count(distinct e.employee_code) as emp
from company c join lead_manager l on c.company_code = l.company_code
join senior_manager s on c.company_code = s.company_code
join manager m on c.company_code = m.company_code
join employee e on c.company_code = e.company_code 
group by c.company_code) AS ctable 
join company on company.company_code = ctable.code
order by ctable.code;

I figured out that if I removed the 'AS' at the end of the subquery the error goes away, like so:
select ctable.code, company.founder, ctable.lman, ctable.sman, ctable.man, ctable.emp
from (select 
c.company_code as code, 
count(distinct l.lead_manager_code) as lman, 
count(distinct s.senior_manager_code) as sman,
count(distinct m.manager_code) as man,
count(distinct e.employee_code) as emp
from company c join lead_manager l on c.company_code = l.company_code
join senior_manager s on c.company_code = s.company_code
join manager m on c.company_code = m.company_code
join employee e on c.company_code = e.company_code 
group by c.company_code) ctable 
join company on company.company_code = ctable.code
order by ctable.code;

As far as I am aware the AS operator is just a way to set an alias in a more verbose way, so why does it fail when trying to alias the subquery with AS vs. without AS?  It is working when I alias the column names within the subquery with AS.

what can I say? It is Oracle. Sometimes it works very strange with AS-clause

Every dialect of SQL has slight differences. In Oracle's case, the syntax doesn't allow aliasing sub-queries with AS. You may as well ask why is blue blue?

That's just the way it is.

If you really desire AS for sub-query alias, use WITH ctable AS (SELECT ...) SELECT ... FROM ctable JOIN ...

@WernfriedDomscheit, that's not quite the same as aliasing a block, a CTE is a reusable block that once used twice will materialize as a temp table. While semantically it results in the same results, the performance implications are quite different.

The syntax does not allow it.
From the SELECT documentation:

table_reference::= 


There is no AS between a query_table_expression and t_alias.

If you look at the SQL99 standard then the AS keyword is optional before a correlation name (alias). Not allowing the AS keyword does not violate the standard.

+1 for the useful diagram and links to the documentation and standard. But I don't agree with your conclusion that Oracle doesn't violate the standards. I read the standards as saying "this keyword is optional for the query", not "this optional keyword does not need to be implemented". On the other hand, no database implements the entire standard, so it's not really a big deal.

@JonHeller I very carefully did not say that Oracle fully implements the standard (as you said, no database does). Oracle's implementation of table aliases could be considered a sub-set of the standard since either using or not using the AS keyword is allowed under the SQL99 standard and Oracle's syntax chooses to implement only one of those options, not using the AS keyword. With regard to table aliases, anything that complies with Oracle's syntax also complies with the SQL99 standard so Oracle's syntax does not violate the standard (even if it doesn't fully implement the standard).
